# list<Rectangle> с Javascript

Tags: javascript, qt, qml, qtquick

Хочу, чтобы по ключу можно было обращаться к объектам.

Объявляю свойства так:

```
 property var timeTable: { "Monday": list<Rectangle>(23) };
```

Потом обращаюсь:

```
timeTable['Monday'] = [ idRect ]
console.log(timeTable['Monday'].objectName)
```

Пишет ошибку:

> qrc:/admin/admin/AdminCost.qml:261: TypeError: Type error
>   qrc:/admin/admin/AdminCost.qml:27: ReferenceError: list is not defined

Как правильно написать объявление структуры данных?

Comment: `timeTable['Monday'] = [ idRect ]` - тут чтото не то)

Comment: можно вопроизводимый пример?